# Erro ao emular AVD no android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, avd

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

erro ao tentar emular um device no android studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele deixa criar o device, mas na hora de emular da esse erro, já pesquisei, mas não conseguir nada relacionado.

Comment: Tem certeza que está criando o avd? Agora está gerando o .ini?

Comment: Sim. Consegui que ele fizesse isso da seguinte forma: Instalando as atualizações e criando uma pasta avd dentro de .android, ficando assim: .android/avd.

Comment: Depois de seguir essas dicas desse link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=197254   consegui fazer que alguns emuladores rodem, porem ele não encontram meu aplicativo.

Comment: ele executa o emulador, mas na hora de abrir o app: 00:37:54 Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
00:39:59 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 2m 1s 400ms
00:40:10 Session 'app': Error Installing APK

Comment: não tem uma pasta apk e um arquivo .apk no diretorio. Por que será isso?
12/19 00:40:04: Launching app
The APK file /home/henrique/AndroidStudioProjects/Unidos/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK

Comment: Tem certeza que todos os drives necessários estão instalados e que a versão do android do emulador também foi instalada? Tente reinstalar, talvez o pode ter corrompido ou algo assim...

Comment: Pessoal. obrigado pela ajuda. Vou rodar o app via depuração usb mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado a @seamusd e Renato Vieria Dantas. Já foi um avanço grande da quantidade de erros que estava dando, agora ele simplesmente só não encontra o app e da um erro de aparentemente não conseguir escrever na pasta .android, mas todas as permissões estão ok. Vou tentar arrumar esses 2 ou 3 bugs que ficaram ai posto aqui. :D

Comment: Quando você compila, se compila, seu `.apk` vai ficar dentro do diretório `...app\build\outputs\apk`. Tente verificar lá. Se não estiver, você está tendo outro problema. =)

Comment: kk Esta lá sim.

Comment: Tente usar o seu proprio celular android como emulador

Comment: Boa dica @GersonArtur. Quando eu tava brincando com android eu fiz isso, muito útil usar via depuração usb. Obrigado.

Comment: Use o terminal para lançar o android studio
alem de permitir as permissões de superusuario é muito mais provavel de  que não acontecera esses problemas novamente

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, Boa tarde!

Você tentou isso?

Com a atualização do Android Studio, a Google, passou a usar `libstdc++`, e ela é incompatível com driver Intel instalado em seu sistema.

Verifique se seu sistema tem os pacotes: `lib64stdc++6` and `mesa-utils`, se não tiver instale utilizando os comandos abaixo:

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6 mesa-utils
```

Em seguida, faça o link simbólico das bibliotecas para o caminho das ferramentas do android sdk

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++

sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og

sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida, olhe no fórum de https://askubuntu.com/questions/867081/android-studio-buggy-after-upgrade-to-16-10/867093